# Mr Cool Ductless Mini Split 9k BTU

Tags: electrical, wiring, mini-split

I am trying to figure out the wiring for this model I am installing. The minimum circuit and max fuse is 15 amps. What size wire and breaker do I need? Also do I need a disconnect for this mini split?

Comment: Don’t know if it helps but the run from the mini split to the main panel is around 70 ft.

Comment: Are you in the US? Mr cool 15 amp wire size is 14awg and yes you need a disconnect.

Comment: Does the amp size matter for the disconnect?

Comment: The least expensive disconnect will be a 30 or possibly 60 amp nema 3r case for outside locations under 20$